# HOw can we add a TextView (in selected rows only) dynamically in a custom Listview?

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to add a TextView in a custom ListView created using array adapter. But this Textview is not in all rows. How can I add it in selected rows?

Comment: Show your code that you may have done so far? If you are facing any issue then show logcat output.

Comment: You mean to say that the textview is there in each of the rows, but according to the data sent to the array adapter, only textviews for some rows will only be used. Thats it right ?

Comment: @Chaitanya yes exactly.

Comment: So, you might be having data corresponding to what all positions you have to put a textview right ?

Comment: Actually, I have some list of questions. Each question have category.  I want to show category wise question.
 i.e  category name
question1
question2
question3

category name2
question1
question2
question3

Comment: Do you have fixed number of categories or it depends ?

Comment: Categories not fixed. I am getting response from server (with qId, question, category,) and need to send the response to server with qid and answer (getting answer from edittext in row)...

problem is with category wise listing , I am not able to set the position and qid of question, as qid is required to send response to server.